# How to make log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter work with acceptOnMatch set to false

Tags: log4net, episerver

I've just started using log4net and have some issues with filtering using strings.

I'm trying to remove EPiServer specific logging in my log4net log file as I am not interested in it.

I have the following log4net configuration for an appender:

```
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
           <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
        </filter>

        <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
            <stringToMatch value="EPiServer" />
            <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

I only have one root logger. This config does not stop the EPiServer logging.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your StringMatchFilter to a LoggerMatchFilter

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
  <loggerToMatch value="EPiServer" />
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />  
</filter>
```

A StringMatchFilter filters on the content of the log message, where a LoggerMatch filters on the Logger's class Name or partial Namespace

Comment: I only use the root logger and I guess EPiServer does as well, so maybe that's why I can't make this work for me?

Comment: Just to clarify: I tried to use the filter as suggested, but still EpiServer entries show up in the log file.

Comment: The filter element needs to go within the appender you've chosen, not within the root element.

Comment: also move the levelrangefilter to the end of the chain, otherwise all DEBUG messages are already passed through

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the line

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

From the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter.html):

> You can add this filter to the end of a filter chain to switch from
>   the default "accept all unless instructed otherwise" filtering
>   behavior to a "deny all unless instructed otherwise" behavior.

Which effectively reverses the logic to deny all messages unless explicitly whitelisted inside a `<filter>` using `<acceptOnMatch value="true" />`